# The Goland or Pycharm program opened by X Server in mobaxterm cannot be entered a language other than English

Tags: pycharm, ubuntu-18.04, xserver, goland, mobaxterm

I have a virtual machine in `Ubuntu 18.4` with `PyCharm` and `Goland` installed in it. I use `Mobaxterm` to remote my virtual machine on `Win10`, and then execute `Goland`'s runtime script in the terminal.

The `Goland` program I then opened worked just like it did on my `Windows 10` computer, and it was very easy to debug. However, I cannot enter Chinese in the `Goland` program opened by `Mobaxterm`. This is a little inconvenient.

Is there any solution?
My `Ubuntu` VM already has Chinese input method installed. I can also input Chinese when I open `Goland` in the VM (using VMware), but not when I open `Mobaxterm` remotely.

When `Goland` opened with mobaxterm, it looks like this:
[image]

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: You can try the following workaround: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-265128

Comment: My problem is not that I can't type Chinese in Goland, I can use `Goland` (type Chinese in `Goland`) in `Ubuntu` `VMware`, but I can't use `Goland` when I open it with `mobaxterm`.@s0xzwasd

Comment: As another idea, you can try to run some GUI apps and input Chinese there to confirm that it is IDE (Java) specific issue. If you're using X11-forwarding, it is better to try without remote connection, right away from the PC where IDE is running if possible.

Comment: I use mobaxterm to open Chrome also can't enter Chinese. Using mobaxterm to open Goland and debug programs is much easier than using the remote debugging and SFTP functions provided by Goland in Windows 10.@s0xzwasd

Comment: So, if you can't enter Chinese in Chrome too, I don't think that the problem is related to the IDE. Speaking about SFTP, you can pay attention to the new run targets feature: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/run-targets.html